# Wine Installation conflict with Ardour / Jack

Tags: wine, dependencies, jack, ardour

i tried to install wine via the software center (version wine1.6 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) and console. In both cases wine wants to uninstall Ardour, Jack, Rosegarden and a few more.
How can i install wine without doing that?

`apt-cache policy wine1.6`

```
wine1.6:
  Installiert:           (keine)
  Installationskandidat: 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4
  Versionstabelle:
     1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`sudo apt-get install wine1.6`

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benötigt:
  hydrogen-drumkits libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386
  libatspi2.0-0:i386 libaubio4 libav-tools libavfilter3 libcairo-gobject2:i386
  libcairo2:i386 libcolord1:i386 libcurl3:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386
  libdbusmenu-glib4:i386 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:i386 libdbusmenu-gtk4:i386
  libgconf-2-4:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgnomecanvasmm-2.6-1c2a
  libgraphite2-3:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libguess1
  libharfbuzz0b:i386 libidn11:i386 libjasper1:i386 liblilv-0-0 liblrdf0
  liblv2dynparamhost1-1 libmowgli2 libnspr4:i386 libnss3:i386
  libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386
  libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386
  libpixman-1-0:i386 libraptor1 librtmp0:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
  libsdl2-2.0-0 libserd-0-0 libsord-0-0 libspeexdsp1:i386 libsratom-0-0
  libsuil-0-0 libtie-ixhash-perl libva-glx1 libvamp-sdk2
  libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386
  libxcb-shm0:i386 libxft2:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml-twig-perl
  libxml-xpathengine-perl libxtst6:i386 mpv python-pyasn1 python-twisted
  python-twisted-conch python-twisted-lore python-twisted-mail
  python-twisted-names python-twisted-news python-twisted-runner
  python-twisted-words rubberband-cli sndfile-programs sndfile-tools wavpack
Verwenden Sie »apt-get autoremove«, um sie zu entfernen.
Die folgenden zusätzlichen Pakete werden installiert:
  fonts-horai-umefont libasyncns0:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386
  libexif12:i386 libflac8:i386 libgd3:i386 libgif4:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386
  libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port10:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libguess1
  libieee1284-3:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmowgli2 libmpg123-0:i386 libodbc1
  libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 libpulse0:i386 libsane:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0
  libsndfile1:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386
  libva-glx1 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx1:i386 libwrap0:i386
  libxpm4:i386 mpv ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 p11-kit-modules:i386 p7zip unixodbc
  wine-gecko2.21 wine-gecko2.21:i386 wine-mono0.0.8 wine1.6-amd64
  wine1.6-i386:i386 winetricks
Vorgeschlagene Pakete:
  isdnutils-doc isdnutils-doc:i386 libgd-tools:i386 gphoto2:i386 gtkam:i386
  libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386 gstreamer-codec-install:i386
  gnome-codec-install:i386 gstreamer0.10-tools:i386
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386 libmyodbc odbc-postgresql tdsodbc
  unixodbc-bin libportaudio2:i386 libroar-compat2:i386 pulseaudio:i386
  hplip:i386 hpoj:i386 libsane-extras:i386 opencl-icd:i386 dosbox:any
Empfohlene Pakete:
  libasound2-plugins:i386 unixodbc:i386 wine-mono0.0.8:i386 wine
```

`sudo apt-get install wine1.6`

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benötigt:
  hydrogen-drumkits libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386
  libatspi2.0-0:i386 libaubio4 libav-tools libavfilter3 libcairo-gobject2:i386
  libcairo2:i386 libcolord1:i386 libcurl3:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386
  libdbusmenu-glib4:i386 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:i386 libdbusmenu-gtk4:i386
  libgconf-2-4:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgnomecanvasmm-2.6-1c2a
  libgraphite2-3:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libguess1
  libharfbuzz0b:i386 libidn11:i386 libjasper1:i386 liblilv-0-0 liblrdf0
  liblv2dynparamhost1-1 libmowgli2 libnspr4:i386 libnss3:i386
  libpango-1.0-0:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386
  libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386
  libpixman-1-0:i386 libraptor1 librtmp0:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
  libsdl2-2.0-0 libserd-0-0 libsord-0-0 libspeexdsp1:i386 libsratom-0-0
  libsuil-0-0 libtie-ixhash-perl libva-glx1 libvamp-sdk2
  libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386
  libxcb-shm0:i386 libxft2:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 libxml-twig-perl
  libxml-xpathengine-perl libxtst6:i386 mpv python-pyasn1 python-twisted
  python-twisted-conch python-twisted-lore python-twisted-mail
  python-twisted-names python-twisted-news python-twisted-runner
  python-twisted-words rubberband-cli sndfile-programs sndfile-tools wavpack
Verwenden Sie »apt-get autoremove«, um sie zu entfernen.
Die folgenden zusätzlichen Pakete werden installiert:
  fonts-horai-umefont libasyncns0:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386
  libexif12:i386 libflac8:i386 libgd3:i386 libgif4:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386
  libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port10:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libguess1
  libieee1284-3:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmowgli2 libmpg123-0:i386 libodbc1
  libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 libpulse0:i386 libsane:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0
  libsndfile1:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386
  libva-glx1 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx1:i386 libwrap0:i386
  libxpm4:i386 mpv ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 p11-kit-modules:i386 p7zip unixodbc
  wine-gecko2.21 wine-gecko2.21:i386 wine-mono0.0.8 wine1.6-amd64
  wine1.6-i386:i386 winetricks
Vorgeschlagene Pakete:
  isdnutils-doc isdnutils-doc:i386 libgd-tools:i386 gphoto2:i386 gtkam:i386
  libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386 gstreamer-codec-install:i386
  gnome-codec-install:i386 gstreamer0.10-tools:i386
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:i386 libmyodbc odbc-postgresql tdsodbc
  unixodbc-bin libportaudio2:i386 libroar-compat2:i386 pulseaudio:i386
  hplip:i386 hpoj:i386 libsane-extras:i386 opencl-icd:i386 dosbox:any
Empfohlene Pakete:
  libasound2-plugins:i386 unixodbc:i386 wine-mono0.0.8:i386 wine
Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT:
  a2jmidid ardour calf-plugins devede hydrogen jack-keyboard mencoder mplayer2
  qjackctl rosegarden zynjacku
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert:
  fonts-horai-umefont libasyncns0:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386
  libexif12:i386 libflac8:i386 libgd3:i386 libgif4:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386
  libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port10:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libguess1
  libieee1284-3:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmowgli2 libmpg123-0:i386 libodbc1
  libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 libpulse0:i386 libsane:i386 libsdl2-2.0-0
  libsndfile1:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386
  libva-glx1 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx1:i386 libwrap0:i386
  libxpm4:i386 mpv ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 p11-kit-modules:i386 p7zip unixodbc
  wine-gecko2.21 wine-gecko2.21:i386 wine-mono0.0.8 wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64
  wine1.6-i386:i386 winetricks
0 aktualisiert, 49 neu installiert, 11 zu entfernen und 23 nicht aktualisiert.
Es müssen 136 MB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 359 MB Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n]
```

Comment: Accept the solution via `LANG=C sudo apt-get -y install wine1.6` and **after** that  `LANG=C sudo apt-get install a2jmidid ardour calf-plugins devede hydrogen jack-keyboard mencoder mplayer2
  qjackctl rosegarden zynjacku`. Add the output into your question.

Comment: Your suggestion worked fine. This is my first question ever, so do i need post / do anything now?

Comment: I write an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you wrote in your comment:

> Your suggestion worked fine.

here is my comment as answer:

Accept the solution via

```
sudo apt-get -y install wine1.6
```

and **after** that

```
sudo apt-get install a2jmidid ardour calf-plugins devede hydrogen jack-keyboard mencoder mplayer2 qjackctl rosegarden zynjacku
```